Unable to load driver 'None' error while running pyttsx3.init() in Blender Python
When I am executing below given python script in Blender, getting the below error, how to resolve it. Also, the same issue was faced during execution in local python, after troubleshooting, it was fixed. Then copied all the packages from local python library to Blender Python site-package library but still having an issue.
Python Script:
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

text="Hello World"

engine.say(text)

engine.runAndWait()

**Error:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 24, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 27, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName=driverName, debug=debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 50, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _win32sysloader: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.3\4.3\python\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 31, in init
    raise RuntimeError("\n\nUnable to load driver '%s'" % driverName)
RuntimeError: 

Unable to load driver 'None'


Hello, this doesn't really seem to be related to Blender ? It seems the environment is still missing some package.
